# A function builder in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, higher-order-functions

A function I'm supposed to build is supposed to take in a list of numbers as a parameter, and give a single function as an output that does as follows: If the number in the list is a positive number, add it, if it is negative multiply by it, and if it is 0, square the number.

For example, if I pass in (4 -1 0), it should return a function that takes in a single parameter, adds 4 to it, multiplies it by -1, squares it, and returns that.

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm getting seriously confused at this point. I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, but any help getting there would be amazing. Here's what I have so far:

```
(define (buildseries L)
  (define (a x) 
    (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
  (define (m x) 
    (lambda (y) (* x y)))
  (define (s x) 
    (lambda (x) (* x x)))
  (define (funcfind d)
    (cond
     [(null? d) (a 0)]
     [(> d 0) (a d)]
     [(= d 0) (s d)]
     [(< d 0) (m d)]))
  (funcfind (first L)))

((buildseries '(2)) 2)
```

I don't know how to build a function that is a composite of other functions... Just feeling lost here.

Comment: Go back to basics. Your input is a list, a recursive data type. Write a recursive function. What are the two variants of a list? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon's answer is very good. You should try to implement it as much as you can. If you need to, you can also refer to my answer here (which doesn't follow Jon's approach since I wrote most of my answer before he posted his):

```
(define (fun nums)
  (lambda (x)
    (let loop ((nums nums)
               (value x))
      (if (null? nums) value
          (let ((num (car nums))
                (rest (cdr nums)))
            (cond ((positive? num)
                   (loop rest (+ value num)))
                  ((negative? num)
                   (loop rest (* value num)))
                  ((zero? num)
                   (loop rest (* value value)))))))))
```

You should study it to see how it works, then write your own version using a completely different approach, like Jon's idea about using `compose`. :-)

---

Edit: The function I wrote can be simplified further: using SRFI 1's `fold`, you can do this:

```
(define (fun nums)
  (define (step num value)
    (cond ((positive? num) (+ value num))
          ((negative? num) (* value num))
          (else (* value value))))
  (lambda (x)
    (fold step x nums)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice words :-) It's interesting to see both versions side by side: reminds me a bit of the interpreter vs. "compiler" evaluators in SICP chapter 4.

Comment: Indeed, the two approaches are interesting to compare. In fact, `compose` itself can be implemented using both approaches, too. Here's my "compiler"-like approach to implementing `compose`: http://refactormycode.com/codes/836

Answer (score 3):

I think you're pretty close to a solution. If I were you, I would define two more helper functions as inner definitions of `buildseries`. One would be an `identity` function that just returns its argument unchanged. The other would be a helper function, `compose`, that takes two functions `f` and `g` and returns a new function that computes their composition. This will look something like your `a` and `m` helpers, which are also "function factories" returning an anonymous function which depends on their argument. You might think about translating the following math-ish notation, using `.` to represent function composition, into Scheme: `(f . g)(x) = f(g(x))`.

By the way, I think your definition of `s` is not quite right: it doesn't need to be a "function factory" that returns a lambda, but simply a plain function of `x`. It *will* work as written, but since you're not doing anything with the (outer) argument `x` you might as well simplify it to `(define (s x) (* x x))`. Then in your `(= d 0)` case you can just return `s`, which is a perfectly good function value itself.

Now you need to think about two things. First, what is your base case? What function do you return when the list `l` is empty? Next, when `l` is non-empty, how will you combine whatever you do with the `first` element of the list with whatever you do, recursively, with the `rest` of the list?

Hope that's helpful. Let me know if I can improve the answer!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the definition of s was correct, but it seems to work when I test it. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Hope it works for you! Having just tried it for myself, I'll just add that using this method there is a slightly tricky issue with the order of arguments to `compose`...

Comment: By the way, love the subtle hints. Nice touch

Comment: After doing all that, another fun thing to try is to `map` the numbers into a list of closures, then `fold` or `reduce` with `compose` to build the desired function in "one" step. :-)

Comment: I would have suggested the same thing. Map the numbers into a list and then fold them with compose. That's much less code than doing it recursively. If you do it this way, you need to be careful about which fold you use.

Comment: @JoshInfiesto: Thanks, this is interesting and puzzled me at first. Since function composition is associative, it seems like left and right folds should be equivalent here. In Haskell they are: `foldl (.) id [(+ 4),(*(-1)),(**2)]` and `foldr` with the same arguments return the same mathematical function. For this problem `[f,g,h]` needs to map onto `hgf`, not `fgh`, which can be done by using `(flip (.))` in place of `(.)`. Racket's `foldl` flips the argument order of its functional parameter, compared to Haskell, so `(foldl compose ..)` gives us `hgf`, and `(foldr compose ..)` gives `fgh`.

Comment: Two notes: `fold` from [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap) passes arguments in the same order as Racket's `foldl`, and the author notes that "MIT Scheme and Haskell flip F's arg order for their reduce and fold functions." [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 hours](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/tutorial/stdlib.html) gives a definition of the Haskell-style `foldl` in Scheme.

Comment: @JonO You're right, hahaha when I said "numbers" I meant functions. And in Haskell, you're right, it would be a non-issue. And in this instance, it's a non-issue with Scheme. I brought that up as a general sort of thing, since you can fold functions with side-effects in Scheme :(

Comment: @JoshInfiesto: No, I thought you were quite clear. I was confused because I was thinking of left- and right-fold as the left- and right-associative interpretations of an infix operator -- `foldr` reducing to `f.(g.(h.id))` and `foldl` to `((id.f).g).h`. Haskell's folds follow this definition, but Racket/Scheme's left fold differs: it reduces to `h.(g.(f.id))` because of the opposite order of the arguments to its functional parameter; and composition is associative, but not commutative.

Comment: @JoshInfiesto Oops, posted that before I finished typing. What I thought was interesting is that the differing results don't really arise from the fundamental difference between (iterative) left-fold and (recursive) right-fold, but simply the order of operands to the folding function. For an associative operator we can get the correct result from either fold. At least, I *think* I understand it now!

Comment: @JonO Yes, I too typed before thinking. I think the important thing is that each of the functions being composed needs to itself be associative, and then either fold yields the correct result. Otherwise, this is obviously not the case.

Comment: Even better, we could say that functions form a Monoid under "compose."

Answer (score 1):

first,you need a primitive function bulider that takes a number and make a correspondence function:

```
(define (num->fun d)
  (cond [(> d 0) (lambda (x) (+ x d))]
        [(= d 0) (lambda (x) (* x x))]
        [(< d 0) (lambda (x) (* x d))]))
```

then,you can map this function to a list of number,it returns a list of functions to be composed:

```
> (map num->fun '(4 -1 0))
=>'(#<procedure> #<procedure> #<procedure>)
```

so you can use high order function **compose** to compose this list of functions:

```
(apply compose (reverse (list-of-functions)
```

be careful,the **compose** compose functions in a reversed order,so reverse the list of function before compose.
you can abstruct that out:

```
(define (buildseries L)
  (apply compose (reverse (map num->fun L))))
;try it:
((buildseries '(4 -1 0)) 1);=>25
```