# Map a list of functions to a list

Tags: scheme, map-function

This is homework, so I don't want the answer. I only need a push in the right direction. I am required to map multiple functions onto a list. For instance:

```
(map-multi (list plus-one square) '(4 5 6)) => (25 36 49)
```

I am able to have it map the first function to the elements of the list, however, I get very lost after that. Also, since this is introductory, I am limited to introductory functions (`const`, `append`, `car`, `cdr`, `member`, etc.)

```
(define (map-multi f l)  
    (cond  
        ((null? l)  
            l)  
        (else (cons ((car f) (car l))  
            (map-multi f (cdr l))))))
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to apply the composition of the functions in your list (should your example have `square` rather than `double` in order to get the result shown?). You might find the answers to this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919732/a-function-builder-in-scheme/9920006#9920006 .

Comment: Sorry, yes, it should be square.

Comment: How many functions can be passed in the list of functions? always two? less than two? more than two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *compose* the functions you receive in the `f` parameter. For simplicity's sake, let's say that there are only two functions in the list - then you need to apply the first function to the current element in the list of numbers and then apply the second function to the result of that. If you can use the [`compose`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html) procedure go ahead with it and change this line in your code:

```
((car f) (car l)) ; you're applying only the 1st function! what about the 2nd?
```

... with this one:

```
((compose (cadr f) (car f)) (car l))       ; now we're applying both functions
```

If you can't use `compose`, then replace the same line with this one:

```
((cadr f) ((car f) (car l)))               ; now we're applying both functions
```

Now, if the problem is more general and you're required to map a list of functions with *more than two* elements, then once more replace the same line in your code with this:

```
((compose-multi f) (car l))
```

And implement a helper function that composes and returns all the functions in the list, by successive calls to `compose`. This one is left as an exercise for you, given that it's homework - but if you understand how the above code works for just two functions, it should be easy enough to extend the result for a list of multiple functions:

```
(define (compose-multi flist)      ; procedure for composing a list of functions
  (if (null? flist)                ; if the list is empty then
      <???>                        ; return the identity function
      (<???> (compose-multi <???>) ; else compose the result of recursive call
             <???>)))              ; with the current element in the list
```

Notice that the identity function is required for handling the case where there are no elements in the list of functions; it's very simple to define, it just returns the same value that was passed as parameter.

Also be aware that `compose-multi` returns a *function*, the result of composing all the functions in the list - `compose` does this for you, but if you're not allowed to use it just remember that this:

```
(compose x y)
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
(lambda (n) (x (y n)))
```

Comment: I'd assume that the size of the function list isn't actually fixed at 2. If that were the case, why use a list instead of two arguments?

Comment: @sepp2k Well, let's ask the OP. And why use a list? because that's what OP's teacher asked for his homework :) . If you're right and there can be more than two functions in the list, then the problem is a bit more interesting, but I doubt that's what the OP was asked to do - this looks like an early assignment for some programming course.

Comment: Of course it's what the teacher told them to do, but that doesn't invalidate my point. Why would the teacher tell them to use a list instead of two arguments if there will only ever be two arguments? Teachers usually have a reason for the things they tell people to do, too.

Comment: `second` and `first` aren't standard scheme functions.

Comment: The size of the list of functions is not fixed at two. It can be of any size. Also, yes this is an intro course.

Comment: (define first car)  (define second cadr)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to write this as two functions. One takes a list of functions and a single input, and applies all the functions in the list in series. The output from one function application will be the input for the next one; once you run out of functions you're done.

The other function will simply map this helper function across a list of inputs.

Comment: I'd have to email the professor to see if that is legal, or if it must be implemented as a single function. The way you described would be much easier.

Comment: The helper function could also be an internal function using `define` or `letrec`, if you've covered those in the course.

Answer (score 1):

To get warm, start with a simpler problem. Then generalize the solution.

How would you write this function?

```
(define (map-single fs x)
  ...)

> (map-single (list double add1) 3)
7
```

That takes a list, `fs`, of function values as argument and a number, `x`, and computed the value of applying the (composition of) functions in `fs` to `x`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way to define `multi-map` which instead of composition uses the operation called `fold`.  Since you're only allowed to use introductory functions, this is not really the answer to your assignment.  But it will be, if you write your own definition of `fold` (it isn't very long!)

```
(define (multi-map operations input)
  (fold map input operations))

> (multi-map (list 1+ square)
             '(4 10 8))
$2 = (25 121 81)

> (multi-map (list 1+ square 1+) 
             '(4 10 8))
$3 = (26 122 82)
```